# чтение папки и файла потом вывод содержимого

Tags: php, html

Чтение папки и вывод содержимого, после нажатия на файл происходит вывод его содержимого. В моём случае это txt файл. Функция для вывода содержимого у меня есть. Достаточно осталось сделать чтение папки и вывод файлов, после нажатия выводился путь до них. Из пути я выведу текст.
Очень нужно помогите!

Answer (score -1):

```
$dir = 'C:\\xampp\\';
$files1 = myscandir($dir);
$files1=array_values($files1);
foreach ($files1 as $key => $value) {
echo "<br>";
echo $dir.$value;
}
```